# No mitzvah to wear tefillin every day?

Tags: tefilin, shiurim-measurements, time, mitzvah, sources-mekorot

I heard that the Bet HaLevi and the Peri Megadim hold that there is no Mitzva for a person to don Tefilin everyday. Can someone source these opinions and explain exactly what they are meaning to say?

Comment: maybe instead of "everyday" you heard "all day"?

Comment: I learned the other day that the Maharam of Rotenberg said that there is no obligation whatsoever to wear Tefillin on Tisha Bav. Perhaps these people hold similarly (to some extent). Also, could someone please source where the Bet HaLevi says this?

Comment: @DoubleAA I heard today that it was the Brisker Rov who said there is no mitzvah min haTorah to put on tefillin every day. I'm still curious to know where that is then and if it exists. Someone said R' Moshe Shternbach brings in down in a Teshuva.

Comment: http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=4693

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59165/759

Comment: if one didn't have to put on tefillin every day then how often would one be obligated to put them on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Peri Megadim Eshel Avraham 37:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=61)

I always understood that they mean to say that the mitzva is to have them on always and there is no difference if you wear it for 1 hour today and 1 hour tomorrow or two hours today and none tomorrow. Each second is its own individual mitzva independent of what day it is on. It is actually kind of hard to justify why each date should matter.

Comment: I can't see any reason to say that logic doesn't make sense. Interesting, there is a Gemara (Rosh Hashana 16 or 17) that says "a skull that Tefilin were never placed on it is called 'poshe yisrael begufam'." I think the Gr"a used a different Girsa- "a skull that tefilin weren't placed on it for *one day* are called 'poshe etc."'.

Comment: @HachamGabriel It's RH 17a. Either one of those girsaot is fine for our purposes.

Comment: I thought this Peri Megadim means that if you don't wear Tefilin one day there is no Isur. However, I think the Gra's girsa contradicts that.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Ah I had read it as "for at least one day" but I see where you are coming from. Can you find the original hebrew version? I don't see it on the daf. That may help us sort this out.

Comment: Hebrew version of what?

Comment: @HachamGabriel The Gra's girsa change. Where does he say that?

Comment: The Rif, Rabenu Chananel and the Semag, Rabenu Bahya have it with "Meolam" but Tosafot has it without Meolam. So it dates back further.

Comment: By the way- thanks for the changing of the title. It makes it more provocative.

Comment: Zohar HaHadash 49a Ahare Mot says "Meolam". As well as the Shut Min  Hashamayim sim. 50. Elya Raba 25, 32. Yabia Omer 4 O"H sim. 14. And more.

Comment: I think this Pri Megadim is saying that ideally one should have Tefillin on the whole day, but even wearing them for one second fulfills the Mitzvah. However, if one misses an entire day he has not fulfilled a positive commandment.

Comment: @Menachem I agree that he is saying one should wear it the whole day and just wearing it for one second fulfills the Mitzva- that is Pashut (basically Pashut of course there are those that argue but this is accepted). But I think the Chidush that I heard from the Rov that said this is that whenever you want to put Tefilin you can- it's not a daily Mitzva.

Comment: Does anyone mind explaining why it should be a daily mitzva? We hold night time is zman tefillin too, so really the entire 6 day period between Shabbatot is one long zman tefillin. Why should each day matter?

Comment: @DoubleAA the Gemara says that we don

Comment: @DoubleAA sorry I can't remember the Raaya that Hacham Yishak Yosef brings.

Comment: @DoubleAA I recall hearing R' Chaim Kanievsky bring a proof that it is a daily mitzvah from a mishna in maseches sofrim.  I don't remember clearly, but it had something to do with making a neder to not wear tefillin and seemed pretty clear that it was a mitzva to do so every day.

Comment: @yEz Perhaps from [Hosafa Bet 2:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22498&st=&pgnum=375)? I don't find that very clear at all.

Answer (score 4):

[Pri Megadim (Eshel Avraham 37:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=61) discusses whether the obligation is constant or daily.

Rabbeinu Yonah (Iggeres Teshuva Ois 24) writes that one who doesn’t wear tefillin has close to 300 עונשים yearly (excluding Shabbos and Yom Tov etc.), which sounds like one transgresses the commandment for each day one doesn't wear Tefillin.

The Gemara ([Menachos 44](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=44a&format=pdf)) writes “he who doesn’t fulfill the obligation of tefillin transgresses eight commandments”. Smag (Asei #3) and Shibolei HaLeket (Inyan Tefillin) are clear that one transgresses these eight commandments *daily*.

(See Tosfos [[Menachos 35b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=35b&format=pdf)], where a disagreement is presented as to whether one must tie the tefillin daily.)

The Brisker Rav — quoted by Reb Moshe Shternbuch תשובות והנהגות ח”א [סי’ מ”ט](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=45), ח”ב [סי’ ל](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=36), ח”ג [סי’ י”א](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=15) — held that the obligation is *all* day, and that there is nothing different about today than tomorrow. Therefore, not wearing it for a whole day does not constitute a greater deal of *bitul* (nullification of the commandment) than not wearing it for an hour. See also [Moadim Vezmanim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19961&st=&pgnum=253).