# Eating indoors when it's raining on Sukkos

Tags: halacha, sukkah, eating, weather

If it is raining enough to make eating in the Sukkah unpleasant (enough to ruin the soup or so), then one is exempt from eating in the Sukkah.

Let's say that someone was on their way out to the Sukkah to eat, when it suddenly started raining. Is there any value to postponing their meal until it stops raining in order to be able to eat in the Sukkah, or once it is raining is it just as good to eat inside?

What if someone was not planning on eating, but then it started raining and they "took the opportunity" to not have to go out to the Sukkah to eat?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13576/759 I don't really follow the question. When it's not raining he should go to the sukkah and when it is raining he should leave. What does eating have to do with anything?

Comment: @DoubleAA leaving the sukkah when it's not raining is not an issur.  Eating outside the sukkah when it's not raining is.

Comment: Both sound like Bittul Aseh's to me, unless you are outside the Sukkah for a specific reason. What Issur would there be?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was using the term loosely, as I'm sure you knew I was, and meant bittul aseh.  But there is no bittul aseh to go for a walk outside your sukkah, and many poskim even conclude that you should go to the beis medrash to learn over your sukkah.  Eating, however, has to be done in a Sukkah whenever possible.

Comment: Going to learn is a valid reason. The Talmud says intense learning need not be done in the Sukkah! You can eat outside the Sukkah if you have a valid reason for being there. Why wouldn't leaving the Sukkah for no reason be a Bittul Aseh?

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume for the same reason that you don't make a leishev on just being in the Sukkah.  Chazal saw eating as the primary mode of dwelling.  IAE, I don't see why this affects understanding my question - when it rains, you can't "put on hold" being in the sukkah - either you are in or you aren't.  But you could "put on hold" eating - you could wait.

Comment: Either way you'll go back to fulfilling the Mitzva as soon as possible. That's the important thing.

Answer (score 1):

I saw an idea in the Meshech Chochma on the haftorah for shabbos shuva. Unfortunately I don't seem to have it printed in my edition at home so I can't quote verbatim. His point was that the mitzvah of Succah is different insofar as even if someone is an oness and exempt from eating in the succah, that fact is that Hashem will not treat it as if he performed this commandment properly, which is what happens with cases of oness by other mitzvos. 
If you want to be wary of this opinion, than apparently there is what to gain by eating in the sucvah properly. Namely schar mitzvah.

Comment: "which is what happens with cases of oness by other mitzvos": I thought the general rule (I mean for all _mitzvos_) is _ones Rachamana patreh v'lav k'man d'avad dami_ (or some such): you're **not** considered to have done the _mitzva_. I can't cite a source for that, though.

Comment: @msh210 The Ritva on Gittin 2b/3a would be a start - he says as much there IIRC.

Comment: @msh210 מחשבה טובה המקום מצרפה למעשה מחשבה רעה אין המקום מצרפה למעשה מחשבה טובה המקום מצרפה למעשה דכתיב (מלאכי ג) אז נדברו יראי ה' איש אל רעהו וגו' מחשבה רעה אין הקב"ה מצרפה למעשה שנאמר (תהילים סו) און אם ראיתי בלבי לא ישמע ה' הדא דתימא בישראל אבל בגוים חילופא . ירושלמי פאה פרק א׳ הלכה א׳ קרוב לסוף.

Comment: @YEZ ^^^^^ I'm not sure what you are reffering to. If you meant the begining of כתובות, that sugya is oness as far as קיום תנאי is concerned, nothing to do with קיום מצות.

Comment: He says that oness is not as if it was done, just that you are not held accountable for it.  I may have meant kesubos, it's been a while.  But he says explicitly that oness is _not_ as if you have done something that wasn't done, and only works to have _not_ done something that was done.  The application to t'nai is just application.

Comment: @YEZ eccept that Hashem can be mitzareph limaaseh,   a kiyum for a tnai is a reality. I would definitely choose to see the Ritva inside. Maybe he was discussing oness of aveira. Its hard to guess. But as it stands the yerushalmi def says like the meshech chachma.

Comment: He was discussing oness of not being able to cross the river. I think he even uses the words that @msh210 transliterated.

Comment: Than that's definitely ksuvos. Ok. Research time.

Comment: As I am thinking about it, it may have actually been the Rashba.  I don't know if I had a ritva when I learned kesubos.

Comment: @YEZ i think you are reffering to ksuvosב ע׳ב  אמר רבא ולענין גיטין אינו כן but i dont think it has anything to do with מצות.