# Why does one have to put on Tefillin every day?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilin

Technically, one should wear Tefillin all day. We don't, since we can't keep ourselves clean the whole day.

But we still put it on once a day during Shacharis, since we can presumably keep ourselves clean for such a short period of time.

But lets say one didn't put on Tefillin by Shacharis. Say one was sick, or forgot them at home, or wasn't allowed to due to Tisha BeAv.

The Halacha is one should put them on sometime during the day (or [Mincha](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2918)). Why?

What's the source for our current practice that "one should not let a day go by without wearing Tefillin"?

Comment: @Mefaresh I'm talking about when you already missed it. For example, Tisha Be'Av

Comment: Can you source _any_ of your claims? Who's current practice is this?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Some put on Tefillin for Krias Shema on Tisha b'Av as well.

Comment: Opposite question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13575/759 Again, please source your claims.

Comment: See Tosofos [משעת הנחת](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=35b&format=pdf) in Munachos 35b-36a

Comment: @Yishai I didn't look at the Tosafos carefully, but isn't that discussing tying the *t'fillin* knot(s) (even according to R' Eliyahu, who says it must be done daily)?

Comment: @Fred Having to tie the knot daily (as opposed to, say, weekly) is an interesting proof that each day has a distinct significance (accd to that Tosafist).

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting. Good point.

Comment: Care to source everything else? The claim that Tefillin should be worn at Mincha on Tisha b"Av is barely even relevant to the question... The Shulchan Arukh says Tefillin should be worn every Shmoneh Esrei. That is just a Heter that the 'prohibition' in the morning no longer applies.

Comment: isnt it part of the mitzva of reciting shema?

Comment: See also perek 9 of Eiruvin, mishnah 1 with comments and the Gemara

Answer (score 8):

The fact that a biblical exegesis - Drasha, is needed to exempt the obligation to wear teffilin on Yom Tov and Shabbos, implies that when it is not either shabbos or Yom tov, there is an obligation to wear them every day.

Rav Yitzchok Yosef in his [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (אות ג')](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_3.html) presents this very argument:

> אף ש**שלא נתבאר בפירוש בתורה שצריך להניח בכל יום ויום, מכל מקום מדמצינו
>   פטור מהנחת תפילין לגבי שבת ויו''ט, משמע דבשאר ימים יש חובה להניחן.
>   שהרי נאמר בתורה** (שמות לא, יג): אך את שבתותי תשמרו כי אות היא ביני
>   וביניכם. וגבי מילה נאמר בבראשית (יז, יא): והיה לאות ברית ביני וביניכם.
>   וגבי תפילין נאמר בשמות (יג, ט) והיה לך לאות על ידך. ואמרו בעירובין
>   (צו.) ר''ע אומר יכול יניח אדם תפילין בשבתות וימים טובים ת''ל והיה לך
>   לאות על ידך מי שצריכין אות, יצאו אלו שהן גופן אות. ובמנחות (לו:) תנא,
>   ושמרת את החוקה הזאת למועדה מימים ימימה, ימים ולא לילות, מימים ולא כל
>   ימים פרט לשבתות וימים טובים, דברי ר' יוסי הגלילי, ר''ע אומר לא נאמרה
>   חוקה זאת אלא לענין פסח בלבד. ומפרש בגמ' דקסבר ר''ע דלילה זמן תפילין,
>   ושבתות וימים טובים לאו זמן תפילין. וע' בקידושין (לג:). וכ''פ מרן בש''ע
>   (סי' כט, וסי' לא) דאין מניחין תפילין בשבת וביו''ט. וכ''ה בהקדמת תיקוני
>   הזוהר (דף ג'). **ומכאן יש ללמוד שחייבים להניח תפילין בכל יום, ומן התורה
>   הוא חיוב מתמשך ותמידי משנעשה לאיש, ואינו מתחדש בכל יום, מלבד שבתות
>   ימים טובים וחול המועד**. ומה שאין מניחין תפילין בלילה הוא מדרבנן גזרה
>   שמא יפיח בהם. והיינו כשיכול לא להסיח דעתו מהם. [ילקו''י תפילין במבוא
>   להלכות תפילין. ובמהדורת תשס''ו 
>   עמוד רפח]

*

> Although there is no explicit source that there is an obligation to
>   wear Teffilin everyday, nonetheless from the fact that one is exempt
>   from Shabbos and Yamim Tovim implies that there is an obligation to
>   wear them everyday.

*

Rav Moshe Sternbuch in Teshuvos Vehanhagos (חלק ב' סימן ל') quotes in the name of the Brisker Rav that teffilin is not a new mitzvah everyday single day, rather it is a constant mitzvah.

Comment: I don't understand this argument at all? From this it seems you have to put it on once per week (maybe?). Where did every day come from? He says explicitly that Layla Zman Tefillin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23713/discussion-between-mefaresh-and-double-aa).

Comment: @Mefaresh You had to wear Tefillin all day every day, so that's what Shabbos eino zman tefillin is memaet

Comment: @Mefaresh There's a chiyuv to wear Tefillin every day all day. I would think that it includes Shabbos, comes to tell us no, it's every day all day except for Shabbos.

Comment: @Mefaresh I'm not understanding the sevara (of you and R' Yosef).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin whatever you  just wrote is exactly what the argument is. Or at least how I understand it. Since there is a need to pater teffilin on those days, mashma the default is to wear them everyday

Answer (score 5):

[Tosafos in Shabbos 131](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Shabbat.131a.36.1?lang=en) seems to hold that a Mitzva which is incumbent upon us constantly must be done at least every day.

Comment: +1 He seems to say it must be done once per obligatory period. Tzitzis is each day (night time you are exempt), but Tefillin would be each week (only Shabbat you are exempt). no?

Comment: @DoubleAA What about Succos and Mezuza? Actually, Tosafos is referring to the Shita that the night garment is not excluded.

Answer (score 3):

[Pri Megadim (Eshel Avraham 37:2)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=61) discusses whether there is a daily obligation.

Rabbeinu Yonah (Iggeres Teshuva Ois 24) writes that one who doesn’t wear tefillin has close to 300 עונשים yearly (excluding Shabbos and Yom Tov etc.), which sounds like one transgresses the commandment for each day one doesn't wear Tefillin.

The Gemara ([Menachos 44](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=44a&format=pdf)) writes “he who doesn’t fulfill the obligation of tefillin transgresses eight commandments”. Smag (Asei #3) and Shibolei HaLeket (Inyan Tefillin) are clear that one transgresses these eight commandments *daily*.

(See Tosfos [[Menachos 35b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=35b&format=pdf)], where a disagreement is presented as to whether one must tie the tefillin daily.)

The Brisker Rav — quoted by Reb Moshe Shternbuch תשובות והנהגות ח”א [סי’ מ”ט](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=45), ח”ב [סי’ ל](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=36), ח”ג [סי’ י”א](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=15) — held that the obligation is *all* day, and that there is nothing different about today than tomorrow. Therefore, not wearing it for a whole day does not constitute a greater deal of *bitul* (nullification of the commandment) than not wearing it for an hour. See also [Moadim Vezmanim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19961&st=&pgnum=253).