# Making Up Missed Tefillin-wearing

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilin

Over at [Life in Israel](http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.com), we find the [following interesting psak story](http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.com/2018/12/interesting-psak-tefillin-twice-day-to.html):

> As reported by Kikar, A frum, Haredi, man found himself in a faraway land with no Jews. The beginning of this sounds like the start of a fairy tale.. Anyways, the traveler came across a local Jew - the local was happy to see another Jew and asked to borrow his tefillin and lay them each day the traveler was in town.
>
> When it was time for traveler to leave and head back home, Mr Local Jew made a somewhat difficult request of his new Jewish friend - he asked if he would mind leaving his tefillin behind, for him to keep, and Mr Traveler would be able to replace them with a new pair when arriving back home in Israel. Mr Local Jew has no tefillin and has no way to get a pair, but Mr Traveler could easily get a new pair when he gets back home...
>
> Mr Traveler thought about and happily decided to leave his tefillin for Mr Local Jew. When he got back home, he bought himself a new set.
>
> After the fact, Mr Traveler asked a number of rabbonim if what he had done was correct and proper or if it was wrong - because he left his tefillin behind for Mr Local Jew he had to go a couple of days without laying tefillin until he could replace them! Maybe he was wrong for doing so.
>
> The question was brought to Rav Chaim Kanievsky who said that what he did was proper, but he needs to make up for the days he did not lay tefillin by laying his tefillin twice per day, once at the morning Shacharis services and once at the afternoon Mincha services, to make up for the days he missed. Other rabbonim the question was presented to agreed with this response.

Rafi, the blogger there, notes that:

> The whole story ad [sic] discussion is interesting, but what is most interesting, to me, is the idea that because he missed a few days of laying tefillin he has to lay tefillin twice a day for a few days to make up for it. I don't think I ever heard that before.

My question is, where in any Halachic literature is there a precedent for this suggestion, where we are told that someone who missed a day of tefillin should make it up in this fashion?  (Note that it is possible that this is his own chiddush, and that there is no precedent.)

Comment: Reminds me of making up tefillah by repeating the next tefillah twice.

Comment: This is a famous opinion of the Griz regarding Tefillin after Chol Hamoed. The idea is that there's no obligation to wear them each day, just each moment is a Mitzva. So two hours tomorrow is the same as one hour today and one hour tomorrow. I don't know if this is in his writings though to qualify as "in any Halachic literature". AFAICT it's a new Chiddush not found in earlier sources since it's not really a zero sum game: if you can wear two hours tomorrow and one today, you should wear them all three! That would be the classic position.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59165/why-does-one-have-to-put-on-tefillin-every-day

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/no-mitzvah-to-wear-tefillin-every-day

Comment: There's definitely halachic literature that would seem to flatly contradict this.

Comment: @Alex no question about that...

Comment: It seems a kind of tikune tshuva. This is surely not halachic

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a halachic position, not just a *tikkun* or *teshuva*.

The discussion revolves around a central issue: Is the obligation to wear Tefillin *every* day, or *all* day. [Although we don't wear Tefillin all day, this is only due to our inability to ensure the requisite consistent cleanliness. The question still remains how to define the obligation, which has ramifications to this Psak]

If the obligation is daily, then of course missing one day is something that can never be fixed.

The Brisker Rav — quoted by Reb Moshe Shternbuch תשובות והנהגות ח”א [סי’ מ”ט](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=45), ח”ב [סי’ ל](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=36), ח”ג [סי’ י”א](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49820&st=&pgnum=15) — held that the obligation is *all* day, and that there is no different between one day and the next. See also [Moadim Vezmanim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19961&st=&pgnum=253).

Accordingly, if I wore it tomorrow for the hour I would have worn it today, it is the same *kiyum*. So in a case where one was unable to wear Teffilin for a day, he could and should wear it for extra time the following day (or any other day).

Comment: I don't think this follows automatically from the Brisker Rav's position. If you missed an hour of wearing tefilin, who says you have to make it up at all? (Rabbi Shternbuch in #11 does quote a Tosefta לא מניחן שחרית מניח בצהריים, but he in fact uses that as a proof that there is a daily obligation, implying that without a daily obligation there would be no obligation to make it up at all)

Comment: @ba - I think you misunderstood me. There is more obligation to make it up than there is [min hatorah] to wear tefillin in the first place; the point is that the kiyum is the same. It isn't obligatory, but certainly recommended.

Comment: I think anyone would agree it's recommended, as a fulfillment of a commandment to wear them, but the missing link is why this this must be done to make up for missed days: your answer claims that this is a "halachic position, not a *tikkun*"

Comment: I think @ba's point can be restated as: based on this it's equally recommend to wear them the extra hour in the afternoon whether or not you missed a day last week, so the missing days have nothing to do with it and don't change anything

Comment: The kiyum is the same.

Comment: That might be, but it still wouldn't justify "he could **and should**"